# Error "FBTIAS010E" when configuring Single Sign On Service on Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I keep getting this error whenever I try to configure the Single Sign On service from Bluemix:

1. Added the Single Sign On service that is unbounded.
2. Configure page appears when managing service.
3. Typed a unique ID for the service. I tried different random letters and UUID.
4. Error appears:

> An error has occurred
>
> FBTIAS010E Unable to process the login request. Your session is not valid.
>
> Time:2015/09/05 13:24:56
>   Request address:/mtfim/sps/idaas/auth/openid/callback
>   Error details:FBTIAS010E Unable to process the login request. Your session is not valid.

How do I solve this? Without being able to configure and set up the SSO, I can't bind the service to any apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue seems to be related to an expired session on your Bluemix Dashboard.
I suggest you to start again creating a new instance of SSO service, after logged out and login again on Bluemix Dashboard.